# Mocking camera Intent for layerhq/atlas

Tags: android-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to mock camera intent to send image during chat using [layerhq/Atlas-Andorid](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-Android). The following piece of code for mocking camera intent using espresso works fine, except on Atlas which throws file does not exist error (reason explained below).

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Bitmap x = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(intentsRule.getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.accolade_avatar);
bundle.putParcelable("data", x);
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtras(bundle);
            intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result));
clickItem(MessagePage.attachmentButton);
clickItem(MessagePage.cameraButton);
```

Here is the layer-atlas code for camera intent.

```
private void startCameraIntent(Activity activity) {
    String fileName = "cameraOutput" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), fileName);
    mPhotoFilePath.set(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);
    activity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

The problem is on line

```
mPhotoFilePath.set(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I need to set it to some pre-existing file path like

```
mPhotoFilePath.set("/storage/DCIM/camera/image.jpg");
```

I cannot modify layer-atlas code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For getting full sized captured image, capturing images intents in android works with output path, meaning you need to provide file path for the Camera to save the captured image,
see https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html.
For testing this flow in android test using Espresso, I suggest to fake the output file provided by the caller of the intent (layer-atlas code).
so what you'll need to do is to get the path provided by the caller and save your mock image there.
as far as I can see it is not supported by espresso-intents but its relatively easy do it yourself using espresso, here's a code sample:

```
    //stub intent handling for retreiving RESULT_OK status back
    IntentStubberRegistry.load(new IntentStubber() {
        @Override
        public Instrumentation.ActivityResult getActivityResultForIntent(Intent intent) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            return new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        }
    });
    IntentCallback intentCallback = new IntentCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onIntentSent(Intent intent) {
            //extract output path for captured image from intent
            Uri uriToSaveImage = intent.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
            //save ready-made mock image to the provided Uri
            saveImageToUri(test.R.raw.mockedCapturedImage, uriToSaveImage);
        }
    }
    IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance().addIntentCallback(intentCallback);

    <click triggering code >

    IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance().removeIntentCallback(intentCallback);
```